# Java string split on alphanumeric and new lines?

Tags: java

I have a test.txt file containing several lines for example, such as:

```
"h3llo, @my name is, bob! (how are you?)"

"i am fine@@@@@"
```

I want to split all the alphanumeric characters and the new line into an arraylist so the output would be

```
output = ["h", "llo", "my", "name", "is", "bob", "how", "are", "you", "i", "am", "fine"]
```

Right now, I tried splitting my text with

```
output.split("\\P{Alpha}+")
```

But for some reason this seems to add a comma in the first spot in the arraylist, and replaces the newline with an empty string

```
output = ["", "h", "llo", "my", "name", "is", "bob", "how", "are", "you", "", "i", "am", "fine"]
```

Is there another way to fix this? Thank you!

--

EDIT: How can I make sure it ignores the new line?

Comment: Alphanumeric or Alpha only ?

Comment: why is `hllo` expected to be one token in the output, but stripped of the `3`?

Comment: @sashok_bg alphanumeric

Comment: It is not adding any `comma`, it is empty string. comma is separator between each of the element of the array.

Comment: @Mark Peters is right. Alphanumeric means 3 will get included

Comment: @evelyn: OK but why wouldn't the `3` be considered a delimiter, resulting in `["h", "llo", ...]`?   How do you tell the difference between a delimiter and a character *within* a word that you want to strip from the word?

Comment: Sorry, you are right! @MarkPeters

Comment: The output is different than what you are claiming. `h llo my name is bob how are you i am fine`.

Comment: I was just wondering how to delimit the new line and discard the comma in the front. @YoungHobbit

Comment: The `3` would be considered a delimiter. If you run `"\"h3llo, @my name is, bob! (how are you?)\"\n\n\"i am fine@@@@@\"".split("\\P{Alpha}+");`, it will return `[, h, llo, my, name, is, bob, how, are, you, i, am, fine]`.

Comment: I can't actually replicate the empty value in the newline by copy/pasting your test input, maybe you could give us the result of `Arrays.toString(input.toCharArray())` so nothing gets lost?  It's hard to format in Markdown without losing potentially important whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2):

Java's `String.split()` behavior is pretty confusing. A much better splitting utility is [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html). Their [documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter) goes into more detail about the problems with `String.split()`:

> The built in Java utilities for splitting strings can have some quirky behaviors.  For example, `String.split` silently discards trailing separators, and `StringTokenizer` respects exactly five whitespace characters and nothing else.
>
> Quiz: `",a,,b,".split(",")` returns...
>
> 1. `"", "a", "", "b", ""`
> 2. `null, "a", null, "b", null`
> 3. `"a", null, "b"`
> 4. `"a", "b"`
> 5. None of the above
>
> The correct answer is none of the above: `"", "a", "", "b"`.  Only trailing empty strings are skipped.  What is this I don't even.

In your case this should work:

```
Splitter.onPattern("\\P{Alpha}+").omitEmptyStrings().splitToList(output);
```

Comment: Particularly `omitEmptyStrings()` would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Use your regex, put the result in an `ArrayList` (as that's what you want the data in at the end anyway), then just use `removeIf` to remove any empty strings.

```
String input = "\"h3llo, @my name is, bob! (how are you?)\"\n\n\"i am fine@@@@@\"";

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.split("\\P{Alpha}+")));
arrayList.removeIf(""::equals);

System.out.println(arrayList);
```

Result:

> [h, llo, my, name, is, bob, how, are, you, i, am, fine]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use regex package in java.util.regex.*

It involves Matcher and Pattern.

```
    String input = "h3llo, @my name is, bob! (how are you?)\n"+
            "i am fine@@@@@";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found a " + m.group());
        tokens.add(m.group());
    }
```

P.S A good tool to test your regex pattern is https://regex101.com/